# I have a J-2 visa and I'm currently staying in the USA. Can I work as a visiting scholar or post doc in a university?

Tags: usa, visa

I have a J-2 visa and I'm currently staying in the USA. Can I work as a visiting scholar or post doc in a university? I have a PhD. I kept in touch with some professors. Not sure I can legally take part in academic work.

Comment: You could start by looking at the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-2_visa

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but under J-2 you in some cases can apply for an employment authorization, upon receiving which you can work and get paid at any job. Without it, you cannot perform services for which one would normally receive wages, even if you work for free.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone in J-2 status can apply for an EAD which will authorize you to do any kind of work in the US. I am not sure if universities will accept you as a "visiting scholar" or "post-doc", however.